# Need counter example to series-related statement

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove the following statement is false by providing a counter-example

> If $\lim_{n \to \infty}|\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}| =1$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ diverges.

Can anyone think of the simplest series possible where $\lim_{x \to \infty}|\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}| =1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ converges?

Comment: an example is $a_n=\frac1{n^2}$

Comment: do you mean $n \to \infty$ in the limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a_n=\dfrac 1{n^2}$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}=1$, but [famously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}6$.

Comment: Off-topic. I have a T-shirt with the series of $\pi^2/6$!